# Why are strings copied copied copied...?

Tags: c++

Imagine this little simplified code snip:

```
ostringstream os; 
os << "hello world!";           

string str = os.str().c_str();  // copy of os

list<string> lst;
lst.push_back(str);             // copy of str
```

In WideString there is a function called detach() which gives the responsibility to the called function to handle the mem-allocations.

Is there such a simlar trick for string type?

Comment: [Move](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/1171191) [semantics](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html). `os.str().c_str()` is a pessimisation that stops the compiler doing the right thing in the first place.

Comment: How about `std::shared_ptr<std::string>>` if you care about copying that much?

Comment: Because you're copying copying copying them.

Comment: There's no way to detach the string from an `ostringstream`.  Stringstreams trade performance for a convenient/safe interface.   The most efficient rewrite of your code would be `lst.emplace_back("hello world!");`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use `C++11` you can just use `move`. You can read about move semantics here: [What are move semantics?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106110/what-are-move-semantics)

```
lst.push_back(std::move(str)); // str is moved
```

But here:

```
string str = os.str().c_str();
```

you construct new `string` from `const char*` returned from `c_str`, just remove `c_str` and then C++11 compiler will call move constructor, instead of new string construction.

Comment: `string str = os.str();` will just "do the right thing" anyway.

Comment: @ForEveR, what is the difference between "move" and "copy" apart that str is empty.

Comment: @NECIPS Primarily that `move()` doesn't create a copy.

Comment: Note that there is still a superfluous copy, and there's nothing you can do about it with `ostringstream` because it returns its internal string by value, and gives you no way to move it out.

Comment: Sorry, my mind is today a little bit slow... What do you mean with "create a copy"? Moving is for me the same as copying from one buffer to another one. But I think about pointer bending.

Comment: @NECIPS Moving steals the internals of the original `string`, so avoids allocating memory for, and copying across, the actual character values.

Comment: @NECIPS Moving is *not* the same as copying. Briefly, `std::string a = std::move(b);` will make `a` "steal" the internal buffer of `b`. It's a pointer copy, not copying of contents.

Answer (score 0):

In Qt library there's different *copy on write* approach. For example:

```
QString a = "Hello";   // Create string
QString b = a;         // No copy, `b` has pointer to `a`
a += " world!";        // `b` is copied here, because `a` was modified
```

Regarding `std::string` the C++11 tries to solve this with move semantics. Another question could be if it's good idea to handle memory management in containers like `QString`.